# excel vba sending email validation list

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Currently I have a sheet that sends a email to a specific email address, on this sheet there is a specific validation list with two options. If I select one option it will send an email to the email specified. However if I select the second option nothing happens. And there is no error.

I would like to be able to send the sheet two different email address depending on what has been selected within the list, and press click on the send button.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Sheet1.Range("G31") = "in the cell(see notes below)" Then

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim fName As String

fName = " NIFU - " & ws.Range("Q12") & " " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss") & ".xls"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fPath & fName, xlWorkbookNormal

' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "JABAAR.ALI@ "
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
        .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


    MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"

    Else

    If Sheet1.Range("G31") = "Multiple applicants registered at the same address" Then

   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "JABAAR.ALI@__________ "
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
        .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"

           End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have initialised the Outlook variables toward outside the If statement and it now seems to work.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

dim OutApp as object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
dim OutMail as object
set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

If Sheet1.Range("G31") = "in the cell(see notes below)" Then

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim fName As String

fName = " NIFU - " & ws.Range("Q12") & " " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss") & ".xls"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fPath & fName, xlWorkbookNormal

' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
With OutMail
    .To = "JABAAR@"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
    .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the mail.
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing


MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"
```

ElseIf Sheet1.Range("G31") = "Multiple applicants registered at the same address" Then

```
' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
With OutMail
    .To = "JABAAR.ALI@__________ "
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
    .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the mail.
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"
```

End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out why it was fundamentally not working. You need to declare and set your objects inside both branches of the `IF`. The way it's setup right now, you declare them in the top block, but not the bottom one.

You need to have those lines in the `Else` part as well :

```
dim OutApp as object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
dim OutMail as object
set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Try this code out :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Sheet1.Range("G31") = "in the cell(see notes below)" Then

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim fName As String

    fName = " NIFU - " & ws.Range("Q12") & " " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss") & ".xls"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fPath & fName, xlWorkbookNormal

    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
    ' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "JABAAR.ALI@ "
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
        .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


    MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"

ElseIf Sheet1.Range("G31") = "Multiple applicants registered at the same address" Then

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "JABAAR.ALI@__________ "
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "RESTRICTED:"
        .Body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Thank you, this referral has been sucessfully sent"

End If
End Sub
```